# MVC feedback 3rd party library?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, feedback

I'm developing a new MVC app and I want to include a feedback widget.

Is there any library out there to do this?

I did some research and found nothing!

But I have a pretty nice idea of how to do it: Ajax post with a hide and show div, sending the data I want and a function storing the data in the DB.

But if there is already something out there that also allows admins to manage, categorize and process them, it will be awesome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I may be allowed to self-promote here, you may want to check out [Appygram](http://appygram.com), as it seems like a good fit here.

Appygram is a messaging service that allows you to submit form information via web service, containing your "standard" feedback information (i.e. name, e-mail, message, etc.) as well as custom fields, categorize them into different topics, and either store them for a period of time, forward them via e-mail and/or push them to another web service.

I think what makes this a "good fit" for you here would be the ability to split your feedback up via topics into different categories, as well as the administrative interface, as you can manage your topics and submissions, and if you're interested in forwarding off the feedback via e-mail or web service, all that can be managed in the admin interface as well.  There's also a mobile app for Android to allow you to keep up with incoming feedback on the go.

Anyway, feel free to check it out and hopefully it can help you with your project; if you have any further questions feel free to contact me.  More details are on the website:

http://appygram.com